# missing property in dynamics treated different in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dynamic

I'm taking a look at Robs [Manatee](https://github.com/robconery/Manatee). After converting the json migrations into dynamic objects, he checks to see if a property exists like this:

```
            if (col.nullable != null) {
                if (col.nullable) {
                    sb.Append(" NULL ");
                } else {
                    sb.Append(" NOT NULL ");
                }
            } else {
                sb.Append(" NULL ");
            }
```

When I try to compile this into an wpf application, I get an exception on the first line:

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does
> not contain a definition for
> 'nullable'

So, why does this work when used in a asp.net setting? Or has this something to do with WebMatrix?

Comment: I've seen people have a similar issue when their dynamic object is backed by an anonymous type residing in a different assembly from the one that's accessing it. That may have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm using JsonFx to decode json into dynamics. Will that count as an object backed by anonymous type in a different assembly? Rob uses a json helper available in webmatrix for the same job. Why would that be different?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that webmatrix is using it's own dynamic type rather than an expando. With an expando if a value has never been set, it will throw an exception rather than return null. I'm not sure if json fx will let you use a different "expando" like this object

[.net DynamicObject implementation that returns null for missing properties rather than a RunTimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291704/net-dynamicobject-implementation-that-returns-null-for-missing-properties-rather/6291766#6291766)

The other option is to catch the exception for a messing member.