# .net DynamicObject implementation that returns null for missing properties rather than a RunTimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
dynamic a = new ExpandoObject();
Console.WriteLine(a.SomeProperty ?? "No such member");
```

but that throws

```
RunTimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Throw'
```

Do you know of an implementation of DynamicObject that would return null for missing definitions, or a tutorial on how to create one? Many thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

public class NullingExpandoObject : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> values
        = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        // We don't care about the return value...
        values.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        values[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic x = new NullingExpandoObject();
        x.Foo = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(x.Foo ?? "Default"); // Prints Hello
        Console.WriteLine(x.Bar ?? "Default"); // Prints Default
    }
}
```

I expect the real `ExpandoObject` is rather more sophisticated than this, but if this is all you need...

Comment: Returning true no matter what the result is in `values.TryGetValue` to suppress the error. Thank you sir for the answer!

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this but it's years later and this code still produces two RuntimeBinderException exceptions. Is there any way we can make this work without having it trigger exceptions during every access?

Comment: @Anthony: What do you mean by "produces"? Do you mean you're seeing them in the debugger but then they're being caught?

Comment: @JonSkeet When you run this (or any similar) sample, don't you see the exception thrown and displayed in the console window in Visual Studio? It's not fun to build a framework based on dynamicobject and find that every access to your property bag triggers a RubtimeBinderException; not only are you incurring a performance cost but it clutters up the console window. Surely I must be doing something wrong, but when I see the Skeetmeister's code doing it too I'm left wondering what went wrong with dynamics.

Comment: I can understand throwing it when I don't have a static or dynamic property in place (via the DynamicObject TryXXX intercepts), but to have a class such as DynamicObject built for this very purpose, to be able to intercept such calls and handle them, and find that even if you handle it correctly you still get exceptions thrown at you makes Jack a sad boy. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Anthony: I normally compile and run Stack Overflow examples from the command line - the result of the code *isn't* an exception. Maybe exceptions are being thrown and caught *within* the code I'm calling, but no exceptions make it out of there.

Comment: That's correct, they were being thrown and handled internally; however, this results in exception messages cluttering the output window.