# Passing data from Partial View to its parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have a View and a Partial View, is there any way that I can pass data from the Partial View to the parent?

So if I have `View.cshtml`:

```
<div id="@someDataFromPartialSomehow">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView")
</div>
```

And `_PartialView.cshtml`:

```
@{ someDataFromPartialSomehow = "some-data" }

<div>
    Some content
</div>
```

How would I go about implementing something like this?

I tried to use `ViewBag.SomeDataFromPartialSomehow`, but this just results in `null` in the Parent.

---

**An attempt**

To try get around the problem of data being generated before being called I tried this:

`View.cshtml`:

```
@{ var result = Html.Partial("_PartialView"); }

<div id="@ViewData["Stuff"]">
    @result
<div>
```

`_PartialView.cshtml`:

```
@{ ViewData["Stuff"] = "foo"; }

<div>
    Content
</div>
```

But the call to `@ViewDate["Stuff"]` still renders nothing unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass data from the Partial View to the parent" exactly?

Comment: Well in the example I gave, the idea is that the ID of the wrapping div is being set from the partial view.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could share state between views using the HttpContext.

```
@{
    this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["Stuff"] = "some-data";
}
```

and then:

```
@{ var result = Html.Partial("_PartialView"); }

<div id="@this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["Stuff"]">
    @result
<div>
```

Except that the example you have shown in your question:

```
<div id="@someDataFromPartialSomehow">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialView")
</div>
```

you are attempting to use the `someDataFromPartialSomehow` even **BEFORE** invoking the partial view which obviously is impossible.

Also bear in mind that what you are trying to achieve is bad design. If a partial view can only work in the context of some specific parent, then you might need to rethink your separation of views. Partial views is something that must be INDEPENDENT and REUSABLE, no matter in which context it is being placed. If it assumes things about the hosting parent then there's a serious design problem here.

Comment: I was thinking it more as meta-data being passed to the parent where the parent can make use of it - the PartialView wouldn't complain if that data isn't used so it still is generally independent and reusable - just with added sugar if the parent *can* make use of it.

Clearly the data is being produced after the requirement for it has been called, but this is part of the problem!

Comment: See my updated answer. You could use HttpContext to share data. But once again, please don't do that, it's a terribly bad design. There are better ways to achieve your original goal.

Comment: Thanks for your update - it works a treat - though does feel a bit dirty! What better ways would you suggest?

Comment: I can't suggest a better way because I don't what you are trying to achieve/solve in the first place. In your question you only asked how to pass data from partial view to the parent view but you never explained why you need to do that in the first place.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov What would be the best away to use a reusable prompt that returns a value to the parent view? It seems like it would be bad design to copy and paste the same pop-up prompt code across many views.

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion for you.

Put hidden input fields in the partial view and get them from javascript.

Ex: In _PartialView.cshtml

```
<input type="hidden" id="someDataFromPartialSomehow" value="5" />
```

In your view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var someDataFromPartialSomehow = $("#someDataFromPartialSomehow").val();
});
</script>
```

Note that you have to write the js function inside the document ready function because the partial view should be fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good get-around. Ideally I'll be looking for a pure-asp.net answer but +1 all the same!

Answer (score 1):

So after some thought I came up with this:

`View.cshtml`:

```
@{ 
    dynamic properties = new NullingExpandoObject();

    var result = Html.Partial("_PartialView", (NullingExpandoObject)properties); 
}

<div id="@properties.Id">
    @result
<div>
```

`_PartialView.cshtml`:

```
@{ Model.Id = "foo"; }

<div>
    Content
</div>
```

[Where `NullingExpandoObject` is Jon Skeet's nullable dynamic dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6291766/1185053)

Answer (score 1):

The simpler thing you could do is in _PartialView.cshtml:

```
@model dynamic
@{ 
    Model.Stuff = "stuff things";
}
```

and in parent view:

```
@{ 
    Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView", (object) ViewBag);
}
```

then in parent view you can use:

```
@ViewBag.Stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use **javascript** for this.
I have this hidden textbox in partial view and i want to access it's value in parent view

```
<input type="text" name="allexamcount" id="allexamcount" value="@TempData["allexamcnt"]" hidden />
```

So, simplest way is as follow:

```
var allexamcount = document.getElementById("allexamcount").value;
document.getElementById("examcount").value = allexamcount ;
```