# Is it possible to pass information through a child template to a master template on Umbraco?

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I have a **Master Template** and **2 Children Templates**. I want to pass information from the children to the Master Template (each child template is a different page).

Is it possible? I'm using UmbracoCms version 7.7.4.

Comment: What kind of information? Why?

Comment: It's basically a css class. I have a wrapper in the beginning of the master template and it should have a css class which depends on the child template.

Comment: I was thinking about as Template within Umbraco, but in the end it's a View and PartialView. I used Section and RenderSection from asp.net mvc. Thanks @Eyescream :D

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking they're templates, but in the end, they're a View and a PartialView from ASP.NET MVC. Thinking as ASP.NET MVC, there're 2 options:

**The first one** is to use **Section** and **RenderSection**.

Child: `@section NameOfSection { parameterValue }`

Parent: `@RenderSection("NameOfSection", false)`

**The second one** is to pass information from HttpContext, but then you'll have to call the ChildAction before use the variable in the ParentView (notice **it's a bad design**, you should avoid it). You can see more information here: [Passing data from Partial View to its parent View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766502/passing-data-from-partial-view-to-its-parent-view)