# How to pass data to Index view from another action result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here I am planning to display userIdCount in Index.cshtml. But this count i will get in different action result called GetUser. But when invokes getuser action it will call partial view and bind the results to index page. But I also want to display count of user id's on index view . I tried using TempData but its not working

```
public ActionResult GetUser(string UserName, int? Locality, string ReportType)
{
    UserManager usersManager = new UserManager();
    List<ReportsInfo> reportsList = usersManager.GetRequestReport(UserName, Locality, "usp_GetUsers");
    TempData["UserIdCount"] = reportsList.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count();
    return PartialView("_ReportList", reportsList);
}
```

In Index view I have used something like this below.

```
 <br /><br />
            @if (TempData["UserIdCount"] != null)
            {
                var test = TempData["UserIdCount"];
                <p>@test</p>
            }
```

Comment: So the partial view is a part of the Index page?

Comment: Yes partial view is part of index page

Comment: Since you're returning `reportsList` to the view, why can't you just do `@Model.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count()` in the view?

Comment: try: https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/8442193

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult GetUser(string UserName, int? Locality, string ReportType)
{
    UserManager usersManager = new UserManager();
    List<ReportsInfo> reportsList = usersManager.GetRequestReport(UserName, Locality, 
        "usp_GetUsers");
    ViewBag.UserIdCount = reportsList.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count();
    return PartialView("_ReportList", reportsList);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<p>@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.UserIdCount</p>
```

Comment: Since you're using a partial view, you'll actually need to use a ViewContext. I've updated the code for your html.

Comment: Can you debug your View to see the properties of the ViewBag?

Comment: ViewContext is what you should need to reference ViewBag properties inside a partial view. You might need to move the ViewContext referenceto your top or bottom level view depending on where you define the ViewBag properties. Also, I would verify that your service is actually giving you a real number back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or javascript to do this like.

```
public ActionResult GetUser(string UserName, int? Locality, string ReportType)
{
    UserManager usersManager = new UserManager();
    List<ReportsInfo> reportsList = usersManager.GetRequestReport(UserName, Locality, 
        "usp_GetUsers");
    TempData["UserIdCount"] = reportsList.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count();
    return PartialView("_ReportList", reportsList);
}
```

Make your index page section like this

```
<p id="userIdCount"></p>
```

Add this script in GetUserPartialView

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userIdCount").text('@TempData["UserIdCount"]');
   });
</script>
```

**Remember** to add jQuery file in your view before this script

Comment: Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766502/passing-data-from-partial-view-to-its-parent-view