# Passing data from Partial View to its parent View in asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[This link have a similar answer which works fine but some changes required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230560/11299472)  above answer works fine, but my objective is a little bit different, I wanted to pass the variable from partial view who contains image URL, I want to use that URL in the main view somewhere. the scenario is, calling ajax to load the partial view and displaying in modal, partial view having a lot of ajax which calling controller for fetching folder and files from the server, on the response of ajax I got an image file URL in the partial view, now I want to pass that URL into the main view, how to do that?

---

the main view -> works fine
enter code here

```
$(document).ready(function (){
          $("#button1").click(function ()    
           {
                    $("#modalbodypopup").load("/ControllerName/GetPartial");
                     jQuery.noConflict();
                     $('#imagePopup').modal('show');      
           });   
   });
</script>
```

---

controller -> works fine
enter code here

```
       public IActionResult GetPartial()     
       {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_FileManager.cshtml");
       }
```

---

partial view calling different controller who returning HTML who have a lot of link and folders name and image file name now on the calling of ajax from the partial view, after a successful response, I got a file URL in the variable inside partial view javascript side which I want to pass to the main view because I am displaying that image there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.  Your `GetPartial()` method can do:

```
return PartialView("_FileManager");
```

And as long as the file is in the shared folder, MVC works out the path.

You can also return the contents of a file directly:

```
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(..);
return File(file, "image/png");
```

This allows you to stream the image url directly into the browser.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="partialDataId" value="/UserFiles/images/Screenshot1.png" />      overridig the value in the partial javascript side like  $("#someDataFromPartialSomehow").val(fileURL);  where fileURL=/UserFiles/images/Screenshot2.png , i need fileURL or hidden value in the main veiw in specific place it may be inside input value , hope you got that.